# While Loop causing 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, php-5.6

If i comment out the while loop my code works. I've never had any issues with while loops.  The error says 500 - Internal Server Error "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." Any Help is appreciated.

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=name; Database=main;", "user", "") or die ('001 DB Connection Failed.');

    $final = trim($_POST['po']);
//$final = "1234567','1245698; this is what this variable looks like.

    $sql = "select * from Table where id in ('$final')";
    $table = '';
    $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    echo $sql;
    $table = '<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>header</th>
           <th>header</th>
    <th>header</th>
<th>header</th>
<th>header</th>
<th>header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';


            while ($dataRow = odbc_fetch_array($query))
            {

                $table .= '<tr>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $dataRow['data1'] .'</td>
           </tr>';
        }



    $table .= ' </tbody>
      </table>';

    echo $table;

    ?>
```

Comment: Don't look for server errors client side. Go to your server and view the error logs.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I would check the return value `$query` of  `odbc_exec()`, it could be `FALSE` instead of an ODBC result identifier.

Comment: It returns resource id #2

Answer (score 0):

I would uncomment the while loop, but comment the block inside it.
if it's not 500, it means that $datarow['data1'] that is not exist in the result.

secondly 
`$sql = "select * from Table where id in ('$final')";`

will give you a broken query. `$final` will not have a correct quote/single quote required.